# Is this adjective or adverbial?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

> When are you getting the train back to Adelaide?

Is the phrase *back to Adelaide* an adjective phrase that modifies *the train* or adverbial to *are getting*?

Comment: For the question "When are you driving your car back to Adelaide?", it's an adverbial phrase. Change the question to "When are you taking the train back to Adelaide?", and it can be analyzed either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Back to Adelaide* postmodifies *the train*, and is a ‘qualifier’. Qualifiers can be realised by a prepositional phrase, as in the example, or by a clause, as in ‘the train **that goes back to Adelaide**’.

Comment: 'Back to Adelaide' may or may not modify 'the train' here. It _may_ be doing so (= the Adelaide train) or it _may_ be a directional adverbial  ( 'When are you getting the train [rather than your usual plane] back to Adelaide?').